# Does the WordPress environment in the PHP runtime gets reloaded at the start of every request and unloaded at the end of that request?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I'm trying to understand if the instance of WordPress environment in the PHP runtime still persists after the end of the request to serve other requests?

I've been looking for the answer to this question but I couldn't find it anywhere else on the internet.

Thanks!

Comment: In general, _nothing_ “persists” in PHP after a request is handled. Anything else would have to be explicitly implemented or configured (stuff like opcode caching, etc.)

Comment: Hi 04FS, so does it mean that by default, the wordpress environment will be set up each time a request comes in? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that’s basically how it works.